# Python-How do I find if a variable is a particular class?

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, python-3.4

I'm writing a script in python3. I have a variable named `r` my code is like this:

```
if type(r) == 'twx.botapi.botapi.Error':
     print('Error!')
else:
     print('success!')
```

When i use `type(r)` i get this:

```
<class 'twx.botapi.botapi.Error'>
or
<class 'twx.botapi.botapi.Message'>
```

I tried  using these too but i got no answer:

```
if type(r) == <class 'twx.botapi.botapi.Error'>:
     print('Error!')
else:
     print('success!')
```

How can I find if the class type is a kind of **error** or **message**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on whether the variable points to an instance of a class or the class object itself you can use [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#isinstance) or [`issubclass`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#issubclass), e.g.

```
from twx.botapi.botapi import Error, Message

if issubclass(r, Error):
    print('Error!')
else:
    print('success!')
```

Both functions accept a tuple of objects for the second parameter.

Comment: works like a charm,both `isinstance` and `issubclass` works,but is there any other way than importing `twx,botapi.botapi`?

Comment: @Ali SH: If you have an instance, you can do: `instance.__class__.__name__`.

Comment: instance.__class__.__name__ works better than isinstance or issubclass.thanks for help and support.

Comment: @AliSH There is nothing *better* about using `instance.__class__.__name__`. It may be more convenient in your case, but it leads to the dark side ;) BTW, I am guessing `r` is a return value from some function, right? If so, why don't you *return* `Message` instances and *raise* `Error` instances instead of all this?